# Connecting to AWS EC2 instance using Private Key and Host IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a private key file named awskey.ppk and a host ip address (let's call this 123.45.678.910

I am trying to connect to the EC2 instance using the command line command -

`ssh -i /Users/ashishagarwal/EC2/awskey.ppk ec2user@123.45.678.910`

This is giving me the error:

**Permissions 0644 for '/Users/ashishagarwal/EC2/awskey.ppk' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: /Users/ashishagarwal/EC2/awskey.ppk
Permission denied (publickey).**

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things.

1. `chmod` will fix your permissions. The file needs to be changed to 600 or 400.
2. `ppk` format is used by putty, need to convert the key to pem encoded format. You can use the putty keygen tool for this.

Comment: how do I convert ppk to openssh using a mac ?

Comment: I dont know of a way. The only tool that I know works, is the putty keygen (puttygen) tool. You can open the keyfile and export as openssh key format.

Comment: I finally installed putty on my mac and converted the ppk file to a pem file using the command - `puttygen awskey.ppk -O private-openssh -o awskey.pem`
This just gives me the error - Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: In that case, you are either user the wrong user, or the user is not authorized for the key. Try using `ec2-user`.

Comment: Are you giving the username as ec2-user, or ec2user as shown in the example. It should be ec2-user.

Comment: `ec2-user` is used by amazon AMI's and several others. Third party AMI's may user other default user names such as `ubuntu` or `bitnami`. If someone else set this up, they may have given you access to your own user and not one of the default ones.

Comment: Just figured it out. The username is ubuntu. Not sure if that's one of the default user names or it was set up.

Answer (score 4):

The private key files should have file permissions as 400, which could be changed using

> chmod 400 file_path

Make sure you are using the correct user name like `ec2-user` or `ubuntu` . If you are using unix based system then use .ppk key.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are using Mac or Unix (based on the command line).

Run this command:

```
chmod 400 /Users/ashishagarwal/EC2/awskey.ppk
```

Then run your SSH command again, and it should work.

Comment: Hmm, it sort of worked. It asks me for the password for the SSH Key awskey.ppk. Do I get the IT folks to send this to me or is it possible to connect without the password ?

Comment: You will have to ask whoever generated the PPK file for you - he/she should have the password.